# Vue dynamic component vs router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I would like to ask when do you use dynamic components instead of vue router? Is it good to use dynamic components instead of vue router? I'm referring more to child routes. Let's say we have an app and we have several nav elements. For instance 'About', 'Cases', 'Services', 'Contact' and if we go to each of them there are a few more options displayed. Let's say if we go to 'About' then we have 'Team', 'What we do', 'Our mission' something like that displayed in that page. Other ones have extra links inside as well. So these could be used as child nav or could be loaded as a dynamic component. What would be advantages and disadvantages to use one over another?

Answer (score 3):

With routing you can link to pages easily and refresh them. As dynamic components linking to them would be more difficult and refreshing would revert the component to default state.

In your case I would use routing but you have to weigh the usefulness case by case. Would someone want to link to yourpage/about/team? You can also consider fitting them all to single page and using anchors yourpage/about#team. I imagine crawlers won't be able to access views behind button clicks either, only links.